# Auto Filter using a variable to represent column number

Tags: vba, long-integer, autofilter

I am trying to replace the named column "I" with a Long, in the below code to autofilter:

```
With Range("I1", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter 1, TeamString
End With
```

I have defined **"filterColumn"** as a Long. However I get a run time error: method range of object failure, because my reference of the variable in the below is incorrect:

```
With Range(Cells(filterColumn, 1), Range(filterColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter 1, filterEntry
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```
With Range(Cells(1, filterColumn), Cells(Rows.Count, filterColumn).End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter 1, filterEntry
End With
```

`Cells` parameters are `RowIndex` followed by `ColumnIndex`.